# get the number from class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the div section which is generated dynamically which the class name ends with number.I want to get the number from the class attribute

I want to get the number from the class submission-1 (1),submission-2 (2) and tried as in snippet.I caught the error undefined match function.how to get the number from class attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var num = $('.submission-').attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0];
  console.log(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webform submission-1">
   <span class="first">1</span>
   <span class="second">11</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-2">
   <span class="first">2</span> 
   <span class="second">22</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-3">
   <span class="first">3</span> 
   <span class="second">33</span>  
</div>
<div class="webform submission-4">
   <span class="first">4</span> 
   <span class="second">44</span>  
</div>

<div class="webform submission-12">
   <span class="first">12</span> 
    <span class="second">1212</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: One approach could be to Get the class name, and split the string with '-' as delimiter

Comment: select the element by existing class name ` var num = $('.webform').attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0];`

Comment: Can you let us know expected result clearly?

Comment: if I were you, i will go with data-val attribute to store the numbers instead of  adding in the classname.

Comment: @Miller I agree. I posted an extra example using data-attr

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var classes = $('[class*=submission]').map(function(_,cl) {
    return cl.className.split(" ")[1].split("-")[1]; // or just cl.className.split("-")[1]; 
  }).get();
  console.log(classes);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webform submission-1">
   <span class="first">1</span>
   <span class="second">11</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-2">
   <span class="first">2</span> 
   <span class="second">22</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-3">
   <span class="first">3</span> 
   <span class="second">33</span>  
</div>
<div class="webform submission-4">
   <span class="first">4</span> 
   <span class="second">44</span>  
</div>

<div class="webform submission-12">
   <span class="first">12</span> 
    <span class="second">1212</span>  
</div>
```

Recommendation - use data attributes instead if you can change server code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var classes = $('[data-submission]').map(function(_,sub) {
    return $(this).data("submission");
  }).get();
  console.log(classes);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webform submission-1">
   <span class="first">1</span>
   <span class="second">11</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform" data-submission="2">
   <span class="first">2</span> 
   <span class="second">22</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform" data-submission="3">
   <span class="first">3</span> 
   <span class="second">33</span>  
</div>
<div class="webform" data-submission="4">
   <span class="first">4</span> 
   <span class="second">44</span>  
</div>

<div class="webform" data-submission="12">
   <span class="first">12</span> 
    <span class="second">1212</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct them from the array but since you are looking for a class `submission-` which doesn't exist you can take into account a common class that exists `webform` then you can use method `get()` which converts the jQuery selection novelist into an array and map them to extract the index

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var indexArray = $('.webform').get().map(element => +element.classList.toString().match(/\d+$/)[0]);
  console.log(indexArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webform submission-1">
  <span class="first">1</span>
  <span class="second">11</span>
</div>
<div class="webform submission-2">
  <span class="first">2</span>
  <span class="second">22</span>
</div>
<div class="webform submission-3">
  <span class="first">3</span>
  <span class="second">33</span>
</div>
<div class="webform submission-4">
  <span class="first">4</span>
  <span class="second">44</span>
</div>

<div class="webform submission-12">
  <span class="first">12</span>
  <span class="second">1212</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use .split("-").pop() like this and also if you need number from all elements then you will need to iterate through all elements like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var num = [];
  $("div[class*=' submission-']").each(function(){
   num.push($(this).attr('class').split("-").pop());
  });
  console.log(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webform submission-1">
   <span class="first">1</span>
   <span class="second">11</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-2">
   <span class="first">2</span> 
   <span class="second">22</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-3">
   <span class="first">3</span> 
   <span class="second">33</span>  
</div>
<div class="webform submission-4">
   <span class="first">4</span> 
   <span class="second">44</span>  
</div>

<div class="webform submission-12">
   <span class="first">12</span> 
    <span class="second">1212</span>  
</div>
```